# Answering off topic questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I understand that Stack Overflow wants to keep only good quality questions but if somebody knows the answer to an off topic question that will help the SO and other users that run into the same issue, why is there a mass effort to not answering the question.

Here is the scenario:

New Stack Overflow user with a little bit of reputation
Asks a question looking for resources to get started on app translation
Problem is that its called Localization and Internationalization and there are distinct differences between them.

I answered it with a link so that that user as well as other users could benefit. Not only was the question thrown into a Downvote frenzy pretty much eliminating all the SO reputation. The answer itself was then deleted by an administrator (I believe). By keeping my answer it will help someone else benefit from the same question.

Why do we go through so much effort to not answer an easy question. It seems counter productive.

Here is the post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085717/how-can-i-offer-my-app-in-several-languages/25085782#25085782

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Link only answers are considered low quality answers.
2. Answering bad/off-topic posts only encourages more of the same.
3. 3 downvotes are a frenzy? If it were 10 or more, I'd tend to agree, if the question was an OK one.
4. Resource requests are off-topic for a reason. They are unsuitable for our Q&A format as they get dated and the different answers get voted by popularity rather than value.

Comment: Ok fine... and yes if you have a rep of 10 than -6 will seriously discourage you... I've been in that position before.

Comment: 5. Link rot makes the answer completely invalid.

Comment: You should edit out your point number 4. Mostly because it's not because they become dated - everything software related become dated one day or another. The question can be directed - that's not the problem, according to here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Recomendations are the problem. But asking, for instance, which .net framework namespace you could use to resolve a problem in your app is on-topic. (there's plenty of those on c# top 20)

Answer (score 4):

To start off

> I have only googled and looked on similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but I can't find a tutorial on how to offer my app in several languages.
>
> Does anybody know a tutorial for making an app in several languages, or how to do it?

isn't a good question at all. It is asking a *non-specific* question about an *off-the-site resource*

A link in an answer is a *bad* way of answering a *bad* question. So, downvoters aren't wrong..

Comment: The question was edited. So its better to simply be quiet and not help someone out.

Comment: @logixologist You have the option to leave a comment on the question, if you want to help out.

Comment: yeah ok. Good point. I guess that is the best way instead of remaining silent.

Comment: @logixologist - Yes. As J Steen suggests, you could leave a comment.

Comment: This question could be easily edited to look like this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795025/localization-in-wpf