# answering off-topic questions in comments

Tags: discussion

Someone [asked a clearly off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583899/lme4-p-values-looking-for-a-citation) (looking for a citation); I voted to close, but I also provided the link they were looking for in a comment.  I understand why both [answering off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267503/answering-off-topic-questions) and [answering in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) are considered bad practice, but I'm wondering whether two wrongs make a right in this case. Should I alternatively have

- kept silent?
- invited the OP to chat?
- given the OP a link to a more appropriate forum/venue, and answered their question there?

These all seem silly, but looking for guidance.

Comment: Asking off topic questions is a bad practice.  Stopping SO users from helping anyway requires a very big stick.  Not so sure it would beat the right people.  Just follow your gut instinct.  Mine says that this question should not have been upvoted.

Comment: FWIW I didn't upvote it. Do you have a recommendation?  Should I have kept silent?

Comment: You can't help yourself being helpful.  That battle is yours, we can't help.

Comment: There is no requirement to explain yourself after a Close Vote. But there is also no reason to withhold helpful information! Suppose you know a question would better fit on another SE site; then, *it is helpful* to tell OP where to post it, rather than (practically) saying "go away"! (Subject to aforementioned gut instincts.)

Comment: Also, see the help-center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer