# Are "this is a duplicate" statements made by 'bots or people who don't read the question?

Tags: discussion

While I'm sure that there are many duplicate questions asked, sometimes questions aren't truly duplicates.

So when I get a question flagged as "this question is a duplicate" and I look up the referred question, I can see that while there are some keywords in common, they aren't truly the same question because there are differences in details and/or intended outcomes.

If 'bots were doing automated "duplicate" flagging, I could understand that an algorithm working solely based on keywords.

If it's a human doing flagging a question as a duplicate, I can't help but wonder what criteria are used to identify a question as a duplicate. (To put it politely.)

I'm speaking generally, but if you want a specific example, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258093/order-column-by-a-separate-liststring-variable).  This post isn't in response to any one issue but more of a general pattern the years.

Comment: I'm truly a bot! We'll take over your world. Humans are good for producing energy for us. Think of yourself being a battery.

Comment: Some examples of wrongly flagged duplicates would be helpful.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge I don't think that question was actually flagged as a duplicate. The comment you got there is not the standard one that is generated when a flag is raised or a close vote happens. It looks like that's just a user who thought the other question may be helpful. (Of course, now that I've written that, there *is* a close vote on the question to close it as duplicate. :-/ There sure wasn't one when I first looked. Ironically, the Meta question may have brought the question to the attention of someone who thought it *is* a duplicate.)

Comment: Are you truly looking for discussion, or are you just ranting? That comment was ... a comment. A comment that was actually trying to help you find the answer to your question. Not even a hint of any malice or thoughtlessness. The question is not on hold, closed, or deleted. In general, the people closing as duplicates are trying to help you, by finding questions whose answers answer the question you have. Please take them as such.

Comment: It wasn't a rant. However, i'm seeing this spiral out of control. This site does cause me frustration, so once more, I'll be walking away from this site for a few months.

Comment: Let's lookup for an appropriate dupe here people! I'd appreciate the irony ;)

Comment: They're people, and they aren't perfect.  Your issue isn't what it appeared in the first half.  I read it as an exact dupe until I got to the middle, then saw the error.  The first half definitely looks like a dupe.  Is that a failing on those reading your question and voting to close as dupe?  Yup.  Imperfect bastards.  Is the fact that you're using linq to EF buried in the body of your question a failing of yours?  Yes, it takes two to tango.  I brought that fact up to the top of your question to forestall any more hair triggers.

Comment: They aren't bots but they might as well be sometimes, especially if you use certain trigger words like "null reference exception" or "jQuery".

Comment: @eddie_cat We and others are studding this, not to close vote but to identify possibile duplicate target as question is posted, but already it would be nice if all the possibile duplicates identified by other users, reported by bots where reviewed.

Comment: @PetterFriberg That's cool, I just hope that your automation tools aren't as annoying as the real people who base their close votes purely on being triggered by words they've seen in a lot of newb questions, haha.

Comment: @eddie_cat To me all the duplicate post on SO is a real problem, it becomes always more difficult to find the great answers. Furthermore closing a question is not the end of it, OP should care about the content he post on SO, if not a duplicate OP can easily edit it, explain why not, formulate the question correctly etc. It very easy to get a nice question re-opened and very difficult to get a bad question closed.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Most people use SO to do their job or homework, nothing more, lol. It would be nice if everyone cared about it as a community, I suppose, but I think the way a lot of people on Meta act is so out of wack with reality as to be funny. It's not hard to find great answers, all you have to do is Google whatever it is you're trying to find an answer to and nine times out of ten the answer is right there as the first result in the Google search, answered correctly and in a way that's easy to follow. When it's not, you ask a question. Boom, answered. That is how most people see SO.

Comment: @eddie_cat I must confirm that _@Queen_ is a pretty good and useful bot. I'm owning a gold badge for c++ but may miss a lot of potential dupes, if she won't inform me about these.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge Missed to add to my very 1st comment: ***Resistance is futile!***

Comment: @eddie_cat Meta is meta. it's true that here are present a particular breed of users. I saw you on my latest post and liked your comments, but you should also understand the others since users putting there energy in keeping SO good and people come by to only "solve homework" not caring about the content or the mission of SO. *"it's not hard to google"*, exactly so why do we have all these [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nullpointer)?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I get where people are coming from & I do appreciate and desire to see and share quality content, I just think that the intensity with which some users push the rules is unwarranted and off-putting, and could quite possibly even backfire when frustrated new users who may have at one time wanted to help the community (or could have become a good contributor in the future!) stop caring what a bunch of jerks on the internet think of their questions. :)

Comment: Linked question ("method XXX is not supported by EF") asked many times on SO with answer exactly the same as accepted one... Sounds like good example of question that should be closed as duplicate, but instead answered... Not sure how this is a good example of "duplicate closure rampage".

Comment: @eddie_cat, Yeah lets [fight](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question) this also, but closing if duplicate or off-topic is correct, if OP gets upset about this, I do not think he/she is correct. He/she should read why. try to understand, edit the question etc.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Agreed, if the question is actually a duplicate. :)

Comment: @eddie_cat more or less 80% of all questions in high-traffic tags are duplicates : ), we just don't have the time and energy to find the right one, review them and close'em

Comment: @PetterFriberg Probably so, haha. My original comment was mainly due to me seeing the most frequent contributors to certain popular tags having a knee-jerk reaction to something that looks like a question that's asked every fifteen minutes but actually isn't a duplicate, or is a duplicate, but of something totally different and much harder to find, lol

Comment: @eddie_cat _"... having a knee-jerk reaction ..."_ Mind your wording please!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this whole query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+duplicate+but+different), do some research please.

Answer (score 10):

> ... statements made by 'bots or people who don't read the question?

Why are you presuming that people or even bots don't read the question? The question is mostly minor in these cases.

> If 'bots were doing automated "duplicate" flagging, I could understand that an algorithm working solely based on keywords.

There aren't any bots around doing duplicate close votes directly (at least none that I'm aware of). That would require them having enough rep, which isn't likely the case.

We have bots (like [@Queen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6294609/queen)), that inform us about *possible duplicate* flags occurring, but it's still humans who decide finally. The bots don't do that on their own.

That said, humans can go wrong about these decisions. If there's any reasoning the question isn't a duplicate, it needs to be elaborated in the question itself, to make it up into the active/reopening queues.

---

> they aren't truly the same question because there are differences in details and/or intended outcomes.

The major point of duplicates isn't the exact wording/expectations in the question, but if any answer given in the duplicate Q&A matches the problem appropriately. It's left to the OP to extrapolate their particular problem to accept or decline these.

Comment: And we expect more persuasive arguments than ["This is not a duplicate!!"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+not+a+duplicate+closed%3Ayes)

Comment: @RadLexus Good point. It requires more to reopen of course.