# How to categorize/flag arrogant "We're not here to..." comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sometimes I see responses in comments such as "[So you want us to ... | We're not here to...]"   [do your homework | review and correct your code | ... ].  These come across  as quite arrogant. Admittedly, often it is a deserved response for, (as an extreme example) sloppy posts from new users, first-posting with a generic title such as "PLZ HELP" and cut-and-paste homework problems as question texts.

However, sometimes I see, received, (and used) this type of response even for serious or good questions.

The tone of such comments is arrogant, and uses a "we" jargon that is not justified. "We" often simply means "I", and the usage of "we" in this comment is a psychological trick (appeal to the majority).

Responding to such comments easily evolves into long chatty comment threads, because receivers of the "we-comment" have to both clarify their question, and respond to the presumption, and might do so emotionally.

Is there a way to deal with this type of comment, except flagging?  Regarding flagging, can "we-comments" be added as an extra item to the list of (rude or offensive / 
not constructive / obsolete / too chatty / other…) ? Should they be flagged at all?

Comment: Related [To nuke, or not to nuke- that is the question:](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question)

Comment: *These come across as quite arrogant.* They aren't.

Comment: This is a very difficult issue on SO, some experience users see it as a frank comment to OP, SE likes that user follows the [be-nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.  I personally are tired to see these comments as I am on bad posts. If you have something constructive to post then post, otherwise close, dv and move on. It will be hard for you to find consensus on meta.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an example of a good question that attracted such a comment, but I'd be worried about the _Meta_ effect.

Comment: @halfer Meeh I could probably find many "not so bad" questions, but then again why do people put in energy in posting these comments, that are hardly constructive and just sometimes creates flame war. I also often see multiple users posting comments on same post having fun on newbie question, so the "We" issue can become ugly.

Comment: You can be arrogant back, keeps meta lively.  Or just flag it as "not constructive" like everybody else does.

Comment: Or just don't flag them, as they usually are right on the money. The rampant political correctness that is infecting SO is giving me shivers -- do we really wish to abolish what basically was the added value of the site only a few years ago?

Comment: We are also not here, to add more crap on crap, more stuff that someone needs to clean up. **dv**, **cv** and **move on**, keep it clean and professional

Comment: We are mad as hell and are not going to take this anymore!

Comment: I know I write these kind of comments occasionally, so far, I am not convinced that I need to stop - my reasoning is that I notice a lot of 'homework dumps', seemingly like a misconception of what the site is about at the very least. I consider it far more arrogant for a new member to dump their homework/task/etc on the site and expect someone to complete the answers for them. If they are 'hurt' by this, then it is on them.

Comment: Comment should be just disabled on questions asked by people with less than 10K points. There is no way to politely and nicely recommend people to improve they questions anyway... :)

Comment: Just occurred to me, we dv these questions only and there are repeated complaints about 'dv's without comments'; we dv with a comment, that is direct and non-placating - and we get complaints about us being meanies... lol can't win! (Good thing it is not about 'winning')

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Most of them are. Even suffering from Dunning Kruger effect. Most of the upvoteers of your comment are as well. I flagged some comments. Mods declined without comment. So, I will stop flagging, to avoid banning. So, obviously it is side policy to let medium high rep people do what they want. The real high rep people do anyway have a higher emotional intelligence. The do not need to write, we are not here to...

Answer (score 4):

Flag comment as non-constructive (or obsolete), downvote the post, consider to vote to close and move on.

Don't start flame war and don't console OP.