# How to correctly flag these comments?

Tags: discussion

Re: [How does std::forward work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526598/how-does-stdforward-work)

Under the question, comments #2 and #3 could be flagged for removal as the original offending comment has been removed.  It took re-reading these comments a few times for me to imagine their original intent.

What is the correct flagging category to use in this case?

If these comments should not be flagged, please explain why.

Comment: Aren't they *obsolete*?

Answer (score 3):

These comments were replies to other comments which are now deleted, and furthermore, they do not have any value with regard to the question.

Don't scratch your head twice, [pick a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365) and move on with your life: "obsolete" because the initial comments are already gone, "too chatty", or even "not constructive", because they are completely irrelevant to the question asked anyway. The three apply in this case, and there is no real difference with regard as to how they are handled by moderators. Only "rude or offensive" is a bit different since they are usually [processed faster by moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question/333408#comment388868_333403).

I went ahead and flagged those two comments as "obsolete" (and they are now deleted).