# Are comments saying a question isn't good enough to be answered constructive

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm going to re-word this from my last post . If I ask a question, and people say things along the lines of "are you kidding me? Of course it isn't ..." Or "It would be stupid if ..." And "Well if you did your research than of course it would be ..." Constructive?

They always come of as super passive aggressive, showing that your question isn't asked perfectly enough to deserve an answer, or at least not useful enough for everyone passing by. I just want to ask a question and hopefully receive an answer.

I'm not here to write a question for 30 minutes to make it perfect in every way. If you need clarification, just ask before you start yelling that the question is dumb.

What do you guys think, **are these types comments constructive enough? Should people make requests for more information before invalidating your question?​**

Comment: I fixed your layout and applied a useful tag. See if that still fits your intent

Comment: Thanks​! Still new to meta so I'm not sure if the tags were limited to the suggested ones that first pop up.

Comment: *I'm not here to write a question for 30 minutes to make it perfect in every way* well, sure but I'm not here to wade to tons of crap posts where the OP didn't care a minute to make it reasonable. Why is my time so much less worth then the 5 minutes extra it takes for the OP to format, spell-check, re-read and hit a google search.

Comment: I'm not sure I still fully grasp what the issue is. Is it just the tone of the comments on at first sight lazy/ill-researched questions?

Comment: Except I do try and do these things. I'm saying if I ask a question I have not found an answer to, and it is reasonable, like can i execute JavaScript functions too my website or something like chrome flags using the javascript: tag, what is the problem. I only want to ask a simple question to see if anyone knows

Comment: My question is if comments saying that the OP's question isn't a useful enough or well researched enough question constructive. Keep in mind I only ask a question if I can't find an answer already online.

Comment: _"I'm not here to write a question for 30 minutes to make it perfect in every way... just ask before you start yelling that the question is dumb."_ Yes, and we (the community) are the passive aggressive here

Comment: I just don't get what the "this isn't researched enough" when no answer exists online.

Comment: The problem is that on SO we expect the questions to be useful to future visitors. That means the quality bar is a lot higher. We don't want to solve your problem, we want to solve a problem that might be encountered by other users as well. Just asking a question without showing research/effort/context will indeed be quickly and harshly commented on in the hope it gets improved before close and down voted. Given the sheer amount of posts we don't have time for pleasantries.

Comment: I can give you a good gist of the comments of my posts here "Are you kidding me!? Of course this isn't ... That would be stupid if it ..."

Comment: If you include in your question *I searched for "foo the bar" but that didn't render any results. I tried to waffle a ponnie because based on [link to documentation] that seemed related, so ended up incorporating that in [code example that we can try/shows what doesn't work]*   will be much different received then *Google didn't return my answer* because that latter statement is hardly ever true.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the response to your most recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081591/calling-already-present-functions-with-a-url  -- the answer you got doesn't seem inappropriate to me at all.

Comment: (And to be clear, while that wasn't a great question I don't really fault you for asking it -- I'm sure we've all been in the situation where you get so deep into trying to solve a problem that you start grasping at solutions that are obviously not workable. This wasn't a "didn't do the research" question, it was a "tunnel vision" question.    The answer was a bit brusque, but essentially correct.)

Comment: Totally agree - people should *not* make comments on questions that look unhelpful/non-researched. Just downvote and move on. (If you question would not have "I'm not here to write a question for 30 minutes to make it perfect" I'd probably upvote it).

Answer (score 9):

> Are comments saying a question isn't good enough to be answered constructive

Yes, generally speaking. As to your specific examples:

> If I ask a question, and people say things along the lines of "are you
>   kidding me? Of course it isn't ..." Or "It would be stupid if ..." And
>   "Well if you did your research than of course it would be ..."
>   Constructive?

There was a [big discussion about where the line is for rude or nonconstructive comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question). But the issue here would be whether they should have said this in a better way, not that they shouldn't have said it at all.

(If these examples were comments you actually got at one point then they were deleted, which implies that they are considered rude enough by moderators to warrant deleting them.)

It's OK for users to tell you your question has problems. In fact, there are a ton of discussions and feature requests on meta demanding users to explain what's wrong with their question instead of just down voting and moving on.

*What you're attempting isn't a good idea/isn't possible* is OK. *LMGTFY* is considered rude (to the point where it's automatically blocked, if I recall correctly).